# Sails.js: How to automatically route to standalone actions with wildcard?

Tags: sails.js

Let's say that I have a few standalone routes in my Sails.js app (v1.0.2):
'user/login/',
'user/logout',
'user/reset-password'
...
Now, my current routes looks like that:

```
'GET /api/user/login': {
    action: 'user/login',
},

'GET /api/user/logout': {
    action: 'user/logout',
},

'GET /api/user/reset-password': {
    action: 'user/reset-password',
},
```

Is there a way to get the same results with less code? something like:

```
'GET /api/user/*': {
    action: 'user/*',
},
```

or:

```
'GET /api/user/:actionName': {
    action: 'user/:actionName',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a route with a wildcard, such as '/*', be aware that this will also match requests to static assets (i.e. /js/dependencies/sails.io.js) and override them.

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?wildcards-and-dynamic-parameters

Or you can try using pattern variables to have less code.

Comment: I know. That doesn't answer my question. I'm looking for a way to automatically use the * value (the first dynamic segment) as the action name (if it exists). That way, I won't need to duplicate the route for each action..

Answer (score 0):

May be you can activated

> Automatically expose implicit routes for every action in your app?

in config/blueprints.js file.

Like this all your routes will be exposed and you won't need to specify each route and action.

But it is not a good solution for security reason.

Comment: I agree, that's why I want to be more specific but yet avoid unnecessary duplicated code. So you are saying that I can't do that?